# High precision timed operations with multiprocess application on windows/c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have multiple processes(which are in different exe files generated by subprojects) created by my main program.

What I want to do is running each process for about 1-2 milliseconds within every 40-50 milliseconds major frame. When I use suspend/resume thread to suspend one process(by suspending all threads it have, but each have only one.) and resuming next, only one switch context(suspend old and resume new) lasts about 60 milliseconds. Which is longer even my major frame. By the way I know that using Sleep is not advised within this manner since the only sleep/wake operation lasts 15-30 ms and I dont use any.

If I change the priority of the running process to lower and next process to higher; is it guaranteed context switch to occur by windows within microseconds?
or what should I consider to achieve an only microsecond sensitive process switch?
And I wonder how long a simple Suspend/ResumeThread operation normally takes?

Currently I can't use threads insted of processes since I need the memory isolation of a process and my processes may spawn and terminate their own threads. Does Waithandlers like syncronization methods give me the high precised time?

**Edit**: The proposed sync objcets are in the resolution maximum to milliseconds (Like waitable timers, multimedia timers etc. all get parameter as ms and gives you ms). I need to use QueryPerformanceCounter and other ways to achieve high resolution as I mentioned.

Comment: Trying to impose your will on processes from the outside isn't very likely to work well. Cooperation is more likely to be effective. That said, what you describe doesn't sound much like the solution to any problem.

Comment: Why are you using multiple sub-processes instead of simply using multiple threads in a single process?  In any case, supending/resuming threads is a very bad design. Use [synchronization objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/about-synchronization) instead, such as [Waitable Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/event-objects), etc.

Comment: I need processes because of their nature which threads does not serve like, own protected memory space etc.

Comment: [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) may be of interest as far as the "High precision time" part goes..

Comment: Switching between processes implies (at least) a context switch from the current process to the kernel, some work there, a context switch from the kernel back to user space of the new process - with all that implies in terms of setting up page tables for the new process, clearing caches, maybe paging things in from swap,  etc etc. It's a (relatively) expensive thing to do.

Comment: As you've found out though, process synchronisation is very heavy. So perhaps you should reconsider the design because it really doesn't sound like a solution to any problem.

Comment: @David I'm not sure that switching process is much heavier than switching thread actually, although I have to confess I've never measured it.  Both take a few hundred microseconds, I believe, depending on the hardware of course.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than your proposed solution. As was pointed out already, your proposed solution is not a solution to any problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Remy says, you should be doing this with synchronisation objects - that's what they're for.  Let's suppose that process A executes first and wants to 'hand over' to process B at some point.  It can then do this:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };
HANDLE hHandOffToA = CreateEventW (&sa, TRUE, FALSE, L"HandOffToA");
HANDLE hHandOffToB = CreateEventW (&sa, TRUE, FALSE, L"HandOffToB");

// Start process B
CreateProcess (...);

while (!quit)
{
    // Do work, and then:
    SetEvent (hHandOffToB);
    WaitForSingleObject (hHandOffToA, INFINITE);
}

CloseHandle (hHandOffToA);
CloseHandle (hHandOffToB);
```

And process B can then do:

```
HANDLE hHandOffToA = OpenEventW (EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"HandoffToA");
HANDLE hHandOffToB = OpenEventW (SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"HandoffToB");

while (!quit)    
{
    WaitForSingleObject (hHandOffToB, INFINITE);
    // Do work, and then:
    SetEvent (hHandOffToA);
}

CloseHandle (hHandOffToA);
CloseHandle (hHandOffToB);
```

You should, of course, include proper error checking and I've left it up to you to decide how process A should tell process B to shut down (I guess it could just kill it).  Remember also that event names are system-wide so choose them more carefully than I have done.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the context switch I want to do is done only with the main process and only when a specified time finished, regardless of the sub processes finished their job or not(yeah an rtos like logic). However I will give it a try to make suitable for my approach.

Comment: Well, whatever logic you might want, in terms of scheduling, this is the the correct basic approach - i.e. having each dependent process waiting on a waitable object until it is called upon to do something.  Sleeping or spinning is not the way.

Comment: Ok I got taht. The problem resides before me is The msdn specifies “The handle must have the SYNCHRONIZE access right. For more information, see Standard Access Rights.” where in the Code I should specify this flag. I couldn’t Find That on Google ?

Comment: I thought I covered that in my example.  Did I miss something?  SYNCHRONIZE access is needed to wait on the handle and you specify that when you call `OpenEvent`.  As far as I know, that's all you need to do.

Comment: WaitableTimers and objects need a parameter which is in milliseconds and very low resolution for me.

Comment: That shouldn't matter - it's just a timeout if the event isn't signalled.  If process A calls SetEvent then process B will be scheduled immediately.  You're making very heavy weather of this...  Can I have my 15 points back please?  The solution I posted is eminently workable.

Answer (score 0):

For very high precision one can use the funciton below:

```
void get_clock(LONGLONG* SYSTEM_TIME)
{
    static REAL64 multiplier = 1.0;
    static BOOL alreadyCalculated = FALSE;

    if (alreadyCalculated == FALSE)
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        BOOL result = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        if (result == TRUE)
        {
            multiplier = 1000000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
        }
        alreadyCalculated = TRUE;
   }

    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);

    *SYSTEM_TIME = static_cast<SYSTEM_TIME_TYPE>(time.QuadPart * multiplier);
}
```

In my case sync objects didn't fit very well(however I have used them where time is not critical), instead I have redesigned my logic to put place holders where my thread need to take action and calculated the time using function above.

But still not sure if higher priority task arrives how long does it take windows to take it into cpu and preempt running one.